# Partial application for list of functions

Tags: python, lambda, partial-application

How do you partially apply a list of functions? The following minimal example:

```
def myprint(a,b):
    print 'a: '+str(a)+', b: '+str(b)


l1=[lambda x:myprint('x',x), lambda y:myprint('y',y)]
l2=[]

for f in l1:
    l2.append(lambda:f('!'))

for g in l2:
    g()
```

gives this output:

```
a: y, b: !
a: y, b: !
```

(Naively) expected would be

```
a: x, b: !
a: y, b: !
```

However, `lambda:f('!')` is only executed in the last loop. Then `f` will remain its value from the first loop, i.e. the last element in `l1`. This last element is then used in the two *different* lambdas in `l2`.

**My question:**
How do you make it work as expected?

Comment: **TL;DR**: add `f=f` to the lambda parameters to bind the function at definition time.

Comment: i.e., `lambda f=f:f('!')`

Comment: Indeed a special case of local variables - the specialized answers were still very helpful, thanks.